# Youtube Data V3 API - Channel list function, possible error?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When searching for a channel list, the Youtube Data V3 API returns an integer indicating how many results there are, however, when paging through the response items, this number is never reached.
For example, the latest query indicated 12393 results, but we only got 565 actual channels in response.
I am noticing though that on subsequent searches we seem to get a good amount of new channels that were not in previous queries.

For context, we are running a search for all channels related to the keyword "crypto".
What is the best way to obtain a complete list?

Thank you kindly,
James